# Retrieving minOccurs and maxOccurs from XSElementDecl in XSOM

Tags: java, xml, schema, xsom

I have read a similar topic on the matter:

[getting the minOccurs attribute using XSOM from an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095294/getting-the-minoccurs-attribute-using-xsom-from-an-element)

but the answer seemed a bit suboptimal, especially when there are hundreds of elements in one xsd file. Is it really the only way to do this, or is there a simpler way?

I would like to retrieve it from XSElementDecl if it's at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's not a property of the element declaration, it's a property of the element particle, which is the relationship between an element declaration and the content model in which it is used.

Now, if the element declaration is a local declaration then it's true enough it can only be used in one content model, so the declaration and the particle are one-to-one, and in the SCM defined in XSD 1.1 it seems that if {variety} is local then you can get {parent} to find the containing model group, and then go back over the particles of this model group. But XSOM doesn't seem to reflect the {parent} property, which is not surprising, because it's not there in XSD 1.0, and there doesn't seem to be anything corresponding to the {scope} property either.

So, the API doesn't seem to allow navigation from the Element declaration to the particles that use that declaration. But then, how did you find the Element declaration if it wasn't via the particle?

Comment: It was actually through an implementation of an XSVisitor interface. I've managed to get around the issue by catching the particles in model group declarations, and then assigning their attributes to particular elements. Thank you for your help anyway!